# Bootstrap - Is it possible to that 1st grid and 12th grid colums will be margined by 20px?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have an interesting question about bootstrap.

I was required that my layout will be divided by 12 grids, so that the 1st grid will have a margin-left of 20px and the 12th grid will have a margin-right of 20px, as shown below:

[image]

Is this possible? If so, can you please show me how to implement it ?

Comment: Questions asking us to suggest, find or recommend a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow Stack Overflow

Comment: Hi Paulie. My question is genuine and I haven't found any direct answer. That's why I'm asking it. Can you please give a direct answer for my question ?

Comment: Is it possible...Yes! BUT it is expected that you at least attempt to code this for yourself. Stack Overflow is not a code writing service. I would suggest that you do some additional research, either via Google or by searching SO, make an attempt and. if you still have trouble, come back with **your code** and explain what you have tried and why it did not work.

Comment: Hey Paulie. I'm a newbie and it's OK to ask questions like this. As you could see my earlier question posts they had with research. Believe my I dig in Google so hard before making a post on this but look at the bright side that now everybody can relate to this if they are encountering an issue like this. No harm was made. You were a newbie also at the beginning. Remember that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Bootstrap grid has been [specifically designed](http://blog.codeply.com/2016/04/06/how-the-bootstrap-grid-really-works/) so that the `container`,`row` and `col-*`s all work together. If you want to change the spacing outside the outermost columns change the margin on the `row` instead. Since the container has padding of 15px, and the row has a negative margin of -15px the effective margin of each `row` is 0. Then you take into account the padding of 15px in each column. So to increase it to 20px on the outside of each row, you would increase the negative row margin by 5px like this...

```
.row.margin-custom {
   margin-left:-10px;
   margin-right:-10px;
}
```

Changing it this way it *won't* break the responsive grid and normal percentage widths of the columns. Adjusting the margin or padding on only the first/last columns will [break the grid in various ways](http://www.codeply.com/go/XyCLuVwPw3).

<kbd>[Demo on Bootply](http://www.bootply.com/NknoikmGua)</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

In Bootstrap, columns have paddings instead of margins. But if you want to add margin to your first and last col. Just add the following:

```
div[class^="col-"]:first-child {
    padding-left: 20px;
}

div[class^="col-"]:last-child {
    padding-right: 20px;
}
```

With the example above, the first and last div which include the "col-" part of the bootstrap col classes get these margins. With this solution, it doesn't matter if you use "col-sm-9", "col-md-2" or "col-lg-4" for example.

Good luck!
Chris

Comment: This approach will break the Bootstrap grid: http://bootply.com/Kmiyq8pBts

Comment: Change the margin to padding to tweak it. Padding will not break the grid. I will adjust the answer above.

Comment: Unfortunately col padding adjustments will break the grid too. It breaks the layout on small screens when the cols stack vertically. It also doesn't work with offsets, ordering and column wrapping.

Answer (score 0):

I will suggest you to customize it. But i´m not sure what do you want.
Bootstrap have a `Container` class for your div to act as a wrapper
Test it here [LayoutIt](http://www.layoutit.com/build).
You can customize the default margin and padding of classes as you wish [Customize Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/customize/)
Or if you don´t want to modify the default behavior you can set specific css for it as Chris says